# How do I get $node->body $node->teaser?

Tags: theming, 8, nodes

I'm migrating a large custom module and theme from Drupal 6 and can't work out how to convert references to `$node->body` and `$node->teaser` since they are no longer fields in the node object, right?

Comment: You probably do not need any custom code to do this. Use a Display Mode (a concept from Drupal 7) to set how to display the body (i.e. trimmed = teaser), and then print out the content in twig. If you need to print the body manually, then you can do that as well in twig.  See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!templates!node.html.twig/8 and https://www.drupal.org/node/1918824

Comment: So I can't use just `{{ node.body }}` inside twig? I see some other modules do this, but from my theme I get `"Object of type Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList cannot be printed.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this code in a preprocess hook:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
$variables['node_full'] = $view_builder->view($node, 'full');
$variables['node_teaser'] = $view_builder->view($node, 'teaser');
$variables['body_full'] = $node->body->view('full');
$variables['body_teaser'] = $node->body->view('teaser');
```

And in twig

```
{{ node_full }}
{{ node_teaser }}
{{ body_full }}
{{ body_teaser }}
```

Use the rendered node and configure the view modes full, teaser or a custom view mode. The single rendered field does not work well with other code.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some progress. It seems that

```
{{ node.body.value|raw }}  ** unsafe! **
```

works well but I guess it skipping input filters, and

```
{{ node.body.value }}
```

shows the markup. Not quite sure how to get the body with input filters but not escape the markup.

**Safety notice:**

Don't use the raw filter if you cannot guarantee that the value is safe from unwanted user input!

Comment: In a node template use {{ content.body }} and configure the field in the view mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the body in twig via:

```
{{ content }}
```

After adding this to your THEME.theme file:

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = &$variables['node'];
  $node_array = $node->toArray();
  $variables['node_teaser'] = $node_array['body'][0]['summary'];
}
```

You can pull it up in templates/node.html.twig with:

```
{{ node_teaser }}
```